# Extraction a special part of a text vba Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Format like this in a Cell:

```
S: 7
P: 
M: 1
L:1
K: 1
Q: 7
```

I want to extract each number and write it in another column for example forS: 7 I want to write 7 in coumn BC, for P:0, 0 in coulmn BD and... ( the spaces between the numbers and : are flexible) 
How can I do that with vba?

UPDATE:

```
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objRegMC As Object
Dim objRegM As Object
Dim lngCnt As Long

usedRowCount = Worksheets("Übersicht_2013").UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To usedRowCount
cellAYvalue = Worksheets("Übersicht_2013").Cells(i, "AY").Value
cellAYvalue = Replace(cellAYvalue, " ", "")

Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
.Pattern = "[A-Z]:\s?(\d?)"
.Global = True
If .test(cellAYvalue) Then
Set objRegMC = .Execute(cellAYvalue)
For Each objRegM In objRegMC
'[bc1].Offset(0, lngCnt) = objRegM.submatches(0)
Worksheets("Übersicht_2013").Cells(i, "BC") = objRegM.submatches(0)
lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
Next
End If
End With
Next i
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear, and it risks being closed. Please provide a more detailed example of what you want to do

Comment: What actual cell/cells are you working with? `S1` `P1` etc?

Comment: (S:7 P M:1 and..) are the value of a cell

Comment: Do you want just copy numeric value of cell?

Comment: Ok, so this is all in a single cell?

Comment: Still confused by this. As it stands, the rightmost value is what you want, so `Right(CELLREF,1)` would do what you seem to be asking.

Comment: yes I want to have numeric value of cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) rather than butcher a long string test

This code takes a string

> S: 7 P: M: 1L:1K: 1Q: 7

and puts 7 in `BC1`, leaves `BD1` blank, 1 in `BE1` etc

to point it at a cell - say `A1` - you could use
    `StrIn = Range("A1")`

**code**

```
Sub RecUt()
Dim StrIn As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objRegMC As Object
Dim objRegM As Object
Dim lngCnt As Long

StrIn = "S: 7 P: M: 1L:1K: 1Q: 7"
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
.Pattern = "[A-Z]:\s?(\d?)"
.Global = True
If .TEST(StrIn) Then
Set objRegMC = .Execute(StrIn)
For Each objRegM In objRegMC
[bc1].Offset(0, lngCnt) = objRegM.submatches(0)
lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
Next
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thnk you so much. I think it s my answer. I have two question. 1-What I see here is only for bc column, but what about bd, be,...? 2 if I want to do read each row and do that, what should I do?

Comment: This line `[bc1].Offset(0, lngCnt) = objRegM.submatches(0)` increments 1 cell to the right of `BC1` for *each* numeric match

Comment: I have updated my post, could you please lokk at it, it doesnt work correctly, thank you sooooooooo much